# Need help identifying and getting rid of spacing around an element

Tags: html, css, overflow, spacing

Im facing a problem concerning a weird spacing around the "switch" element. It makes the div "check-lower" get bigger than it's actual content. When I use it in my current project its causing overflow which a cant change by using overflow hidden because its messing up the scaling of the "switch".

```css
.check-lower {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.check-display {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #19ba00;
  font-family: "AminDigitalCaps";
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 170px;
  border: outset 3.5px;
}

.switch {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 195px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 1px 2px black, inset 0 2px 2px -2px white, inset 0 0 2px 15px #47434c, inset 0 0 2px 22px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  perspective: 700px;
  transform: scale(0.25);
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.switch input:checked+.button {
  transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(25deg);
  box-shadow: 0 -10px 20px #ff1818;
}

.switch input:checked+.button .light {
  animation: flicker 0.2s infinite 0.3s;
}

.switch input:checked+.button .shine {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch input:checked+.button .shadow {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch .button {
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  transform-origin: center center -20px;
  transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(-25deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: #9b0621;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(#980000 0%, #6f0000 30%, #6f0000 70%, #980000 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switch .button::before {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 30%, #650000 75%, #320000) 50% 50%/97% 97%, #b10000;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.switch .button::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: linear-gradient(#650000, #320000);
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: translateY(50px) rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 50px 8px 0px black, 0 80px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.switch .light {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: light-off 1s;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#ffc97e, #ff1818 40%, transparent 70%);
}

.switch .dots {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(transparent 30%, rgba(101, 0, 0, 0.7) 70%);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}

.switch .characters {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white) 50% 20%/5% 20%, radial-gradient(circle, transparent 50%, white 52%, white 70%, transparent 72%) 50% 80%/33% 25%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switch .shine {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, transparent 3%) 50% 50%/97% 97%, linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), transparent 50%, transparent 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) 50% 50%/97% 97%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switch .shadow {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes flicker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes light-off {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="check-lower">
  <label class="check-display" id="display-right">Use lowercase</label>

  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="lowercase" class="checks">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="light"></div>
      <div class="dots"></div>
      <div class="characters"></div>
      <div class="shine"></div>
      <div class="shadow"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

I already looked for any possible margin or padding but I cant find none of it. I also tried transform translate x on the switch element but the spacing inside the "check-lower" div keeps remaining so this doesn't do the thing as well.

Comment: i'm sure it is because of display:flex; which causing the issue try to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You need to ditch the scaling and change the width/height values of the switch. Transform is causing the div to think it's children are bigger than they are. See below for an example (you may need to tweak the switch/borders to what you are looking for)

```css
.check-lower {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
border: 2px solid black;
}

.check-display {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #19ba00;
  font-family: "AminDigitalCaps";
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 170px;
  border: outset 3.5px;
}

.switch {
display: block;
background-color: black;
width: 47.5px;
height: 58.75px;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 1px 2px black, inset 0 2px 2px -2px white, inset 0 0 2px 15px #47434c, inset 0 0 2px 22px black;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 20px;
perspective: 700px;
}

.switch input {
display: none;
}

.switch input:checked + .button {
transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(25deg);
box-shadow: 0 -10px 20px #ff1818;
}

.switch input:checked + .button .light {
animation: flicker 0.2s infinite 0.3s;
}

.switch input:checked + .button .shine {
opacity: 1;
}

.switch input:checked + .button .shadow {
opacity: 0;
}

.switch .button {
display: block;
transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
transform-origin: center center -20px;
transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(-25deg);
transform-style: preserve-3d;
background-color: #9b0621;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
background: linear-gradient(#980000 0%, #6f0000 30%, #6f0000 70%, #980000 100%);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switch .button::before {
content: "";
background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 30%, #650000 75%, #320000) 50% 50%/97% 97%, #b10000;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
transform-origin: top;
transform: rotateX(-90deg);
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}

.switch .button::after {
content: "";
background-image: linear-gradient(#650000, #320000);
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
transform-origin: top;
transform: translateY(50px) rotateX(-90deg);
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
box-shadow: 0 50px 8px 0px black, 0 80px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.switch .light {
opacity: 0;
animation: light-off 1s;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: radial-gradient(#ffc97e, #ff1818 40%, transparent 70%);
}

.switch .dots {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: radial-gradient(transparent 30%, rgba(101, 0, 0, 0.7) 70%);
background-size: 10px 10px;
}

.switch .characters {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(white, white) 50% 20%/5% 20%, radial-gradient(circle, transparent 50%, white 52%, white 70%, transparent 72%) 50% 80%/33% 25%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switch .shine {
transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
opacity: 0.3;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(white, transparent 3%) 50% 50%/97% 97%, linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), transparent 50%, transparent 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) 50% 50%/97% 97%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switch .shadow {
transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
opacity: 1;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(transparent 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes flicker {
0% {
  opacity: 1;
}

80% {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

100% {
  opacity: 1;
}
}

@keyframes light-off {
0% {
  opacity: 1;
}

80% {
  opacity: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="check-lower">
                <label class="check-display" id="display-right">Use lowercase</label>
                
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="lowercase" class="checks">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="light"></div>
      <div class="dots"></div>
      <div class="characters"></div>
      <div class="shine"></div>
      <div class="shadow"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```